# How to present and play Video Media to home users

Tags: media-player, media-manager

I have a collection of videos in many different formats.
What are good solutions for presenting the whole collection and playing media to home users?

1. Users working directly on the "server"?(Currently Windows Laptop)
2. Clients running  Windows, Android, Chromecast.
3. Would also like a web interface.

The collection is currently stored on a disk connected to a Windows 7 laptop "server" connected directly via cable a dd-wrt router with quite fast Wi-Fi.  (I can change easily change OS on "server").

28 May:

1. I often need subtitles.
2. With a web interface, it can be interesting to also have access from the outside, and also have access to other kinds of media.

Comment: Take a look at XBMC http://xbmc.org/about/

Comment: As this is not a "how-to" site, could we make your question a little more precise? I guess you're looking for two things here: 1) a DLNA server for that Windows machine holding the files (XBMC might indeed be a solution for that, but also check our [dlna tag](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dlna)), and 2) DLNA clients for the rest (e.g. BubbleUPnP on Android). That would make at least 2 different questions to be asked separately :)

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using VCL from [VideoLAN](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/streaming.html) as it is free, cross platform and describes almost exactly the usage you suggest.

[image: VideoLAL Streaming Solution]

Comment: And the Library Functionality?